# How to use YouTubeRequest in Xamarin.Forms (Portable)

Tags: c#, youtube, youtube-api, xamarin.forms, gdata

I want to upload `Video` in `YouTube` from my account whenever a user clicks on the `YouTube upload button`, I just want to know that what should I do if I have to send the stream content on YouTube. Or how can I get the path of video from Stream Data?

```
string developerkey = "api_key";
YouTubeRequestSettings settings = new YouTubeRequestSettings("Sample", developerkey , "email_id", "password");
YouTubeRequest request = new YouTubeRequest(settings);

Video newVideo = new Video();
newVideo.Title = "Video Title Here || ArgeKumandan";
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("Autos", YouTubeNameTable.CategorySchema));
newVideo.Keywords = "cars, funny";
newVideo.Description = "My description";
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.Private = false;
newVideo.Tags.Add(new MediaCategory("mydevtag, anotherdevtag", YouTubeNameTable.DeveloperTagSchema));
newVideo.YouTubeEntry.MediaSource = new MediaFileSource(@"‪C:\Users\Yudiz\Desktop\small.mp4", "video/mp4");

var createdVideo = request.Upload(newVideo);
```

Thank You.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because This API is deprecated by the Google.

Comment: It is still a valid question even though the API is deprecated people run across the code and don't relies it.   I wouldn't close it.

Comment: Okay. I thought it should be closed, but as you are my senior in SO. ;)

Comment: Trust me if it wasn't a valid question I would have voted it close already and not answered it :)

Comment: I am still searching on the solutions for how to upload video in YouTube. ;(

Comment: All the information you need is in the documentation.   You are going to have to code it all yourself there is no library for Xamarin.  Get Auth working first.   These are the calls you will need to make http://www.daimto.com/google-3-legged-oauth2-flow/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137427/discussion-between-chandresh-khambhayata-and-daimto).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be using the Gdata library for [YouTube API v2.0](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol).  The Youtube v2.0 API is deprecated and no longer works.

> Note: The YouTube Data API (v2) has been officially deprecated as of March 4, 2014. Please refer to our [deprecation policy](https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service#deprecation) for more information. Please use the YouTube Data API (v3) for new integrations and migrate applications still using the v2 API to the [v3 API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/) as well.

Also you can not use client login (login and password) to access any google API.  You will need to use Oauth2 to access the YouTube API.

Answer: Your code will not work as the API you are trying to access is no longer valid.  You will need to switch to using the [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/getting-started).